# Error running app: flag provided but not defined: -config

Tags: chainlink

When I want to run my chainlink node, the following message show at last. Here is my command   `docker run --platform linux/x86_64/v8 --name chainlink -v ~/.chainlink-sepolia:/chainlink -it -p 6688:6688 --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway smartcontract/chainlink:2.0.0 node start -config /chainlink/config.toml -secrets /chainlink/secrets.toml` and I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Can check the [document](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/v1/running-a-chainlink-node) and setup your node step by step. If there is any problem, please share the config and where you got problem.